# Update table with returned id from insert on other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I'm trying to figure out how to insert data from Table1 into Table2, then use the newly-created ID from Table2 to update the corresponding row in Table1.

I'm using Postgres 12.4 for what it's worth

Example:
I've got two tables, e.g. `users` and `metadata`

The users tables has the following columns

```
| id | info | metadata_id |
```

The metadata table has the following columns

```
| id | data |
```

I want to migrate all of my `info` values from the `users` table into the `data` column of the `metadata` table, and update my `users.metadata_id` (currently blank) with the corresponding `metadata.id` values, essentially backfilling foreign keys.

Is there any way to accomplish this gracefully? I've got a working query which locks both tables and creates a temporary sequence to insert into the `metadata.id` and `users.metadata_id` but this seems brittle and I would need to start the sequence after the highest-existing ID in the metadata table, which isn't ideal.

I've also tried to use a data-modifying CTE with a RETURNING clause to update the `users` table, but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: A chained CTE is the way to go. Please post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `returning` here, since you need to keep track of the association of users and metadata while inserting.

I think it is simpler to first pre-generate the metadata serial of each user in a CTE, using `nextval()`. You can then use that information to insert into metadata and update the users table:

```
with 
    candidates as (
        select u.*, nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('metadata', 'id')) new_metadata_id
        from users u
    ),
    inserted as (
        insert into metadata (id, data) overriding system value
        select new_metadata_id, info from candidates
    )
update users u
set metadata_id = c.new_metadata_id
from candidates c
where c.id = u.id
```

We need the `overriding system value` clause in the `insert` statement so Postgres allows us to write to a `serial` column.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a290fa0495c7a00fa64cdcba15463d12)**